# Cordova/phonegap - facebook login with Native FB app and Oauth2

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, phonegap

I am trying to integrate login with Facebook with my cordova app (android platform), but want to use Oauth2 authorization code grant flow (server explicit). I found plugins/manually written code that are using webview or inappbrowser approaches which works fine but these solutions cannot check with FB Native app whether user is logged into FB.

Is there any way to use code flow authorization without inappbrowser, so that if user has FB native app installed, my app would be able to obtain code token without asking the user to authenticate to facebook each time?

Comment: Hi. Did you got any solution for this problem.